# Memory leak with AJAX requests + jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, memory-leaks

I am repeatedly fetching a JSON object from the server with AJAX calls. Over time, the memory usage of the browser grows (tried with Chrome, Safari, Firefox). Using Chrome's heap snapshots, I've discovered that the timestamp strings are being left around with no references. If I a take a sequence of snapshots, I see the number of Strings is continually increasing.

```
$(function() {
    var latestTimestamp = 0;

    function fetchData() {
        $.get("/parameter?format=json&since=" + latestTimestamp, gotData)
    }   

    function gotData(data) {
        latestTimestamp = data['timestamp'];
        setTimeout(fetchData, 250);
    }   

    fetchData();
});
```

Other notes:

- I'm using jQuery 1.7.1.  EDIT: Just tried with 1.6.2 and 1.4.2, same problem.
- The `timestamp` in the JSON object is actually an integer, not a string. So the accumulating strings might be temporary values?
- Removing the `+ latestTimestamp` from the AJAX request stops the leak.
- A faster setTimeout (20ms) causes the leak faster. I thought the fast timeout might be to blame, so I cut it back to 250ms, but that didn't help.

Comment: @Vega fetchData is already there in the code ;) (line 4)

Comment: Maybe JQuery will prefer $.get("/parameter", {format:"json",since:latestTimestamp}, gotData);

Comment: @nikoshr Cool idea. Just tried it, but it still leaks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try cleartimeout javascript function ? if not please try this.

```
var abc=null;
function gotData(data) {
latestTimestamp = data['timestamp'];
data=null;
clearTimeout(abc);
abc=setTimeout(fetchData, 250);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you're done with data[], you can get rid of it:

```
function gotData(data) {
    latestTimestamp = data['timestamp'];
    delete data;
    setTimeout(fetchData, 250);
}
```

Comment: I just gave this a try, but Chrome's heap snapshots still show a constantly increasing number of strings between snapshots.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this problem lies with jQuery and/or browsers. I've seen similar leak with often AJAX calls.

Instead of polling the server 4 times a second consider pushing data from server to client. I don't know what platform you're using, but if it's .Net you might want to take a look at SignalR

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx

Comment: Well, I'm not using .Net, and the server I'm working with is custom and written in C++, but maybe real server-to-client push is something I should look into.